# TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a parent contract:

```
contract Transaction {

enum C_facts {
    Inital,
    Requested,
    Promissed, 
    Declared, 
    Accepted,
    Declined,
    Rejected
}

C_facts public c_fact = C_facts.Inital;
function nextCFact(bool happyFlow) internal {
    if(happyFlow == true){
        c_fact = C_facts(uint(c_fact) + 1);
    }
    if(happyFlow == false && c_fact == C_facts.Requested){
        c_fact = C_facts.Declined;
    }
    if(happyFlow == false && c_fact == C_facts.Declared){
        c_fact = C_facts.Rejected;
    }
}
modifier transitionNext(bool happyFlow)
{   
        _;
        nextCFact(happyFlow);
}
....
```

Then I have a child contract:

```
contract RentalCompleting is Transaction{
function promiseRentalCompleting() public
         atCFact(C_facts.Requested)
         returns (address){
             DepositPaying depositPaying = new DepositPaying(address(this));
             return address(depositPaying);
         }
```

And I want to change the c_fact of RentalCompleting at DepositPaying contract:

```
contract DepositPaying is Transaction {
        RentalCompleting rentalCompleting;
        constructor(address _rentalCompleting) public{
           rentalCompleting = RentalCompleting(_rentalCompleting);}
        function acceptDepositPaying() public
         atCFact(C_facts.Declared)
         transitionNext(true)
         returns (address)
         {
             require(da_invoiceAmount == pm_invoiceAmount);
             rentalCompleting.c_fact() = C_facts(uint(c_fact) + 1);    <=ERROR HERE=>
             return address(rentalCompleting);
         }
```

But i'm getting `TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.` on the line marked by:<=ERROR HERE=>.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is not Java dude! You cannot set a variable of another contract by passing a reference of it in the left hand side of an assignment expression. You need to implement a setter function in the contract where that variable is located, and then call that setter function from the contract where you want to set this variable.

Comment: Depending on your system requirement, you might also need to restrict calling permission on that setter function.

Comment: yup i will need that

Comment: how could i restrict calling permission on that setter function? i did `function setCFact(C_facts _c_fact) public {
        c_fact = _c_fact;
    }` but i don't want to let the user to have access to this function... i changed to `internal` and `private` but i get a compilation error @goodvibration

Comment: Typically, this is done by using a modifier. [Solidity common patterns](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/common-patterns.html) has examples.

Comment: By verifying that `msg.sender` is in the list of addresses allowed to call this function.

Comment: @hrkrshnn: modifiers is just an implementation (technical) detail.